# Plotting a function only non-zero for discrete values of argument

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a function like:

$$
    f(E)= \Sigma_{n=0} \Sigma_{\ell=0} \, \delta\left(E+\frac{\ell+2n+2} {R\sec{\rho}}\right) w(n,\rho,\ell)\,,
$$

i.e. the function is zero unless

$$
E=-\frac{(\ell+2n+2)}{R\sec{\rho}}
$$

and $(n,\ell)$ can take only integer values from zero (the function $w$ is boring and not important for the problem, and $\rho$ and $R$ are just constants.).

How can I use Mathematica to plot this function against $E$?

1) I was thinking of use `Solve` with the domain `Integers` to spit out the (one or) two pairs of $(n,\ell)$ corresponding to each integer value $m=-(\ell+2n+2)$. Then I know that $E_m=-m/(R\sec{\rho})$, and I can compute $f(E_m)$ by summing the (one or) two corresponding $w(n,\rho,\ell)$ functions. Finally I can make a `ListPlot`. This didn't quite work as `Solve` spits out these `ConditionalExpression`s rather than `Integers` for some reason.

Any other ideas?

The `Solve` code I was using:
(for example with $m=-7$)

```
Solve[7 == ell + 2 n + 1, {ell, n}, Integers]
```

Comment: Please include your `Solve[]` code

Comment: Included code now.

Comment: u said R & rho are constants so what are their values.also whats the upper limit of the sums

Comment: Upper limits of the sums are infinity, but I don't need to calculate `f` for an `E` corresponding to such high values, so in principle the cut-off is arbitrary, depending on the range of the plot one wishes to generate. I don't think it is necessary to know the values of the constants, but an example is $\rho=0.5,R=1000$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using solve you can just get your l,n pairs by hand..:

```
pairs[m_] := Table[ { m - 2 - 2 n, n }, {n, 0, m/2 - 1}]

Table[pairs[i], {i, 2, 10}] 

(*
{
{{0, 0}},
{{1, 0}}, 
{{2, 0}, {0, 1}},
{{3, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
{{4, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}},
{{5, 0}, {3, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
{{6, 0}, {4, 1}, {2, 2}, {0,3}},
{{7, 0}, {5, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{8, 0}, {6, 1}, {4,2}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}}}
*)
```

BTW, putting the >=0 conditions in Solve gets you what you want as well:

```
{ell,n}&/@ Solve[{7 == ell + 2 n + 1, ell >= 0, n >= 0}, {ell, n}, Integers]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there an easy way to then build $f(E)$ from this table of pairs? i.e. for each row: compute $E$ and then compute $f(E)$ by adding the $w$ functions from the summand for each $(n,\ell)$ pair in the row...